# How do I extend the Ethernet port of our laptop using switch or without it for NIC teaming purpose?

Tags: networking, switch, ethernet, network-adapter

How do I extend the Ethernet port of our laptop using switch or without it for NIC teaming purpose?

I want to use NIC teaming for faster Internet but my laptop has one Ethernet port, I want to add more.

Comment: Your NIC is going to be faster than the WAN connection, anyway. I do not see speed increase because you are limited by the slowest link.

Comment: If I use kind of load balancing in NIC teaming I will get a lot more speed for sure. Why not ? @RonMaupin

Comment: You are going to be limited by the speed of the WAN link, which is certainly slower than your LAN interface. Assume your WAN link is 200 Mbps, and your laptop interface is 1 Gbps, teaming a second NIC to get 2 Gbps, you will still only get 200 Mbps.

Comment: Yeah I will, but I'm going to use multiple WAN connections at the same time I have multiple routers that have internet connection themselves and I'm going to use all of data transfer speed possible for all of them using NIC teaming so If my WAN link speed is 200 Mbps using 10 of them them I can get 2000 Mbps And that's great but unfortunately I have only one Ethernet port so I can only connect to one router at the same time @RonMaupin

Comment: No, you are confused. A connection can only use one WAN link because each WAN link will have a different WAN address. TCP creates a connection that is based on the IP and TCP addresses, and changing one address will break the connection. That means any single connection can only use one WAN link.

Comment: Let me put it this way , I can control the traffic by NIC teaming so I can Let's say download a file with one IP from google drive and download another file from oneDrive with another IP there will be no problem with TCP and it should be fine. And also we have this far easier in IPv6 using Anycast Addresses @RonMaupin

Comment: You are forgetting that for your PC, you have a default route pointing to the Internet, and only one default route will be the one used. You would need more specific entries in your routing table to send traffic to a different WAN router. In that case, teaming does nothing for you, you just have separate links to separate routers with a bunch of routing table entries in your host routing table. It really is not that practical.

Comment: So your saying there is no way to speed up even with routing table (I don't know what it is !)? @RonMaupin

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. You can get a faster WAN link from your ISP, or change to a different ISP with faster speeds. NIC teaming is really for your LAN. There are routers that have multiple WAN links, and you can set up policy routing to use both links, but unless you get a large router with the full Internet routing table, you are simply going to use a default route to the Internet.

Comment: The Highest speed ISPs provide here is really slow ! , but thanks for your answer you helped a lot @RonMaupin

Comment: NIC teaming is not what you want. If you want two *different* connections with *different* properties, you *don't* want to team the NICs. You either want two NICs or two connections using a single NIC. What you want is called "dual WAN".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extend the Ethernet port of our laptop using switch or without it for NIC teaming purpose?](https://superuser.com/questions/1584178/how-do-i-extend-the-ethernet-port-of-our-laptop-using-switch-or-without-it-for-n)

Comment: You really need to describe your scenario and details of your purpose better. Also. Also what constraints you have. The advice here is *very easy* to misinterpret. One way to "bond" multiple links is to set up multiple vpns to an endpoint outdside your network (eg a vps) and load balance that. This is quite challenging technically but I've done it before. Il Another, easier but cruder way is to set up different routes with different gateways from a router - this likely requires a router with multiple interfaces for WAN use. (Dd-wrt can do this).

Comment: No it does not @harrymc

Comment: Looks like a great term to search for Thanks a lot @DavidSchwartz

Comment: I really don't know what other things should I describe , Let me know so I can make my question better . I want to use the internet I have in two ADSL at the same time using ONE COMPUTER and I have a computer with one Ethernet Port and I don't care about the OS I should install to do this and don't care about devices I should add that's all @davidgo

Comment: Is there anyway to use multiple "one WAN" routers and connect them with switch or something and then connect it to my laptop ( because I found up to only 4 WAN ports on internet that is TL-R470T+ ) ? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @Ali Yes, you can do that. But the switch will have to support VLANs. Otherwise, you'll wind up connecting the two networks to each other and confusing all the machines on each network.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's really your WAN connection you are trying to speed up, you could also order for example two internet connections and "merge" them via:

- using a router with load balancing e.g. DD-WRT
- using a service like [speedify](https://speedify.com)
- you can ask if your ISP allows for bonding two internet connections

Depending on what you need, you should choose the solution accordingly. Keep in mind that load balancing is not the same thing as bonding etc. With load balancing you will have 2x200Mbps, simply speaking in most cases you can download 2 files simultaneously at 200Mbps each but NOT 1 file at 400Mps. If you want 1x400Mbps you need to use bonding or a service.

If you still want to team multiple NICs you can

- add some USB to Ethernet Adapters (e.g. from TP-Link)
- team them using PowerShell (I'm assuming Windows 10) ([source](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1003888-nic-teaming-windows-10-works/)):

  New-NetSwitchTeam -Name "SwitchTeam01" -TeamMembers "Ethernet","Ethernet 2", "Ethernet 3"

Comment: Is it possible to do dual wan using DD-WRT with only one Ethernet on laptop ? ( And maybe using switches ) @Albin

Comment: @Ali yes, the router will handle both connections there will be only one wire to your laptop. But it all depends on your goal - keep in mind that load balancing is not the same thing as bonding etc. You will have 2x200Mbps, simply speaking you can download 2 files simultaneously at 200Mbps each but NOT 1 file at 400Mps. If you want 1x400Mbps you need to use bonding or a service.

Answer (score 0):

(I've done this as an answer as its to big/complex to fit as a comment, and is at least a partial answer to your question)

You can do what you are describing in your comments - ie 1 computer with 2 ADSL connections with different hosts reachable via different ADSL connections without any additional hardware or the use of bonding or teaming.

Step 1 is to set up your ADSL routers in the following way:

- Leave the main router as it is, but make sure that there are IP
  addresses available to it which are outside the DHCP range.  (I'm
  going to assume ADSL router has a range 192.168.1.1, with
  192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.200 available for DHCP)
- While connected directly from the PC to the the second router
  reconfigure it so the LAN interface has an IP address in the same range as primary router, but with a different IP address.   Using the numbering scheme above I would suggest assign the LAN Interface the IP address 192.168.1.254.   **Turn off DHCP on this router**
- Ensure you connect a LAN port from Router 1 to router 2, and then plug the connection from one of the routers (it does not matter much which) to your PC.
- Reconfigure your computer with a static IP address - eg 192.168.1.2.   Set the default gateway to 192.168.1.1 and the DNS servers to 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254.    At this point you will have an Internet connection to your main router, with DNS going through either or both routers depending on how the client decides to resolve domain names.  (You can use other nameservers if you prefer).

In order to move some of the traffic onto the second router add static routes for some IP space to it.  For example, if you want to route about half the internet to it, you could route 0.0.0.0 netmask 127.0.0.0 via gateway 192.168.1.254  - This would route all traffic from 0.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255 down the secondary connection, with the remaining traffic going out the default gateway - ie the first connection.

Comment: Can I use This method for more than two ADSL ( maybe 10 at the same time ) ?
@davidgo

Comment: Can we use them ( two connections ) to route traffic simultaneously rather than set a range of ips for each connection ? @davidgo

Comment: You can use the method for more then 2 connections, although the balancing will become less even and you will see the law of diminishing returns. You can't use this method without lots of hard hacks and limited applicability to route all traffic simultaneously. There are lots of obstacles do doing this " client side only" including NAT and egres filtering.

Comment: @davidgo I don't know... calling this balancing is a... let's say far stretch... ;) Not sure this is what the OP has in mind or if he really understands the limits of your solution, but I like the idea non the less... :)

Comment: @albin it certainly has massive limitations, but this kind of balancing us very similar to the way connections are (or at least circa 1995 when I was peripherally involved were) balanced using BGP.

Comment: @davidgo interesting looks like I have to refresh on BGP a little bit more in detail - is it the same for eBGP and iBGP? But back on the topic initial question: As far as my (rather superficial) understanding of load balancing routers goes, it is session-based and not IP range based!? So in the case of a dual WAN two sessions to the same IP would be using both WANs with a load balancing router but not with your solution, right?

Comment: @albin its IP based, so no, no sharing of 2 connections between 2 a single pair of IPs.